# how do assign a 2d array to another 2d array holding by a map in golang?

Tags: go

I started to learn the golang last week and I am rewriting a python project in golang. I know that golang basically has no concept of inheritance and people suggest using embedding instead. In my project, I have a base structure called `MyBase`, an extended structure called `AdvBase` with MyBase embedded. `MyBase` carries a map of 2d array, each 2d array could be accessed by a key specified by enum. In a different folder, I have a structure `TopTeam` extending the `AdvBase`. The folder structure looks like

```
root
|--- main.go
|--- base
     |--- base.go (MyBase struct & AdvBase struct)
     |--- commons.go
|--- team
     |--- topteam
          |--- tt.go (TopTeam struct)
```

In tt.go, I initialized the map defined in MyBase and I expect that will reflect to all structures with MyBase or AdvBase embedded.

```
// base.go
package base

import "fmt"

type MyBase struct {
    max_num int
    myTool map[KIND]Tool
}

func (b MyBase) SetTool( k KIND, mat [][]int) {
    b.myTool[k].SetMat(mat)
}

func (b MyBase) ShowTool(k KIND) {
    b.myTool[k].Show()
}

type AdvBase struct {
    MyBase
}

func NewAdvBase(max_num_ int) *AdvBase {
    ab := AdvBase{MyBase{max_num: max_num_}}
    return &ab
}

type Tool struct {
    mat [][]int
}

func (t Tool) SetMat(mat_ [][]int) {
    t.mat = mat_
}

func (t Tool) Show() {
    fmt.Println(t.mat)
}

// commons.go
package base

type KIND int

const (
    T1 KIND = 0
    T2 KIND = 1
    T3 KIND = 2
    T4 KIND = 3
) 


// tt.go
package teams

import "base"
type TopTeam struct {
    base.AdvBase
}

func NewTeam(k_ int) *TopTeam {
    p := base.NewAdvBase(k_)
    tt := TopTeam{*p}

    T2 := base.T2
    // I assign the 2d array holding by the map with key=T2
    tt.SetTool(T2, [][]int {{1,2,3,4},  
        {4,5,6},{7,8,9,10,11}})

    return &tt
}

// main.go
package main

import (
    "base"
    teams "team/topteam"
)

func main() {
    pp := teams.NewTeam(3) // calling this should issue tt.SetTool
    pp.ShowTool(base.T2) // so this line should show the assigned array
}
```

However, after running the code, the array with key=T2 is always empty. I have been debugging this issue for the whole afternoon but still get no clue what wrong with the code.

During the runtime, there could be up to 10 instances of `TopTeam` created in the program, each TopTeam maintains a map of `Tool`, and each `Tool` is holding a matrix (2d array) which may change in size or content from time to time. I wish to keep the address of the map and Tool unchanged once they are created, but the array hold by the Tool could be changed. Is it possible to implement this in go?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change a few things:

First, you need to change `SetMat` to use a pointer receiver:

```
func (t *Tool) SetMat(mat_ [][]int) {
  ...
}
```

Without that, `SetMat` receives a copy of `t` and modifies that, which gets thrown away. With a pointer receiver, `SetMat` will modify the `t` instance used to call `SetMat`.

Then, you need to change the  map to store `*Tool`  instead of `Tool`:

```
   myTool map[KIND]*Tool
```

Without that, `myTool[x]` returns a copy of `Tool`, instead of a pointer to the `Tool` instance stored in the map.

Then you have to change where the map is initialized. With your current setup, the map has `Tool` by value, so if an element is not in the map, you get back an empty instance. When you use a pointer, that empty instance will be nil, causing panic.

```
func (b MyBase) SetTool( k KIND, mat [][]int) {
    t:=b.myTool[k]
    if t==nil {
       t=&Tool{}
       b.myTool[k]=t
    }
    t.SetMat(mat)
}
```